# Difference between html and bootstrap classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I started learning django a few weeks ago and the one thing i have noticed and causes me a lot of issues, is the clarification between HTML and Bootstrap classes. I know that when you are creating a tag in HTML, you can add a class in it that can be named anything and then we usually use the class to write CSS, right? But i finished some tutorials and realized that some people just wrote a class like btn btn-warning and a button with styling automatically came up even though they didn't write any CSS for it. And then i tested it with a random name and it was plain blank. Can someone please explain all of this that why when we use some specific names that already customized tag is shown on the website.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can include bootstrap in your project, like you would include any custom made .css file. You can even download the bootstrap file and edit as you please. The idéa behind bootstrap is to have standardized css ruleset for many different projects, meaning that if you know the bootstrap rules/classes, you can quickly setup rather "complex" responsive/mobile-first websites, that otherwise could take a long time to setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML and bootstrap are both somehow similar. Its just that with HTML you will have to manually write all codes to perform any action however Bootstrap saves your time as it has its inbuilt tags that work for specific action.
For example you can create your own navigation bar with HTML or use navbar tag of bootstrap. The navbar however has built in functions so there is less work. You can use in by including bootstrap link in your css like:

But it's kind of tedious to edit the bootstrap tags if you sometimes want to.
And,HTML is mainly used for the basic designs and bootstrap to make it more responsive.You can know about bootstrap more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_bootstrap.asp

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is basically alot of premade css classes

so when you are using Bootstrap in your site you already have those classes and you can just use them
i recommend you to go to W3School and read about it in depth

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for
> developing responsive, mobile-first websites.
>
> Bootstrap is completely free to download and use!

[Bootsrap in W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)